# jQuery slideDown()/slideUp() not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jQuery's "slideUp" and "slideDown" methods to animate a navigation header. The div I'm targeting is appearing and disappearing on cue, but it's not actually animating.

I've looked at a few of the other slideDown/slideUp questions that seem to be addressing similar problems, but the conditions they mentioned don't appear to apply to what I'm doing.

Here's the SCSS for the div I'm targeting:

```
#navSmall {
    background-color: $superDarkOrange;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: $headFont;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

And here's the jQuery function:

```
function navResize() {
    if (w > 1075) {
        if ($('body').scrollTop() > 192) {
            $('#navSmall').slideDown(200);
        };

        if ($('#navSmall').css("display") === 'block' && $('body').scrollTop() < 190) {
            $('#navSmall').slideUp();
        };
}
};
```

Many thanks!

Comment: seems to work fine https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/VWyxKw

Comment: @toofarm: how are you setting the variable 'w'

Comment: Honey, you don't need jQuery, you need media queries and css animations.

Comment: @karthick "w" is the window width. i'm defining it like this:

var w = $(window).width();

Comment: @korona You can detect page scroll with a css media query?